# Передача файлов на другую машину с помощью mpi без знаний о содержимом, с++

Tags: c++, файлы, сеть, mpi

Стоит задача раскидать с управляющего узла json-файлы по вычислительным, причем строго без знания структуры передаваемых файлов. Код на с++. Я так понимаю их в бинарники надо переводить, в таком виде передавать, а потом на вычислительных узлах собирать? Нет опыта в этом, подскажите пожалуйста библиотеки или как это правильнее сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPI передает массивы байт в виде пары (const char*, size_t). Соответственно, в первую очередь нужно перевести ваши объекты в json (если это еще не сделано), json к строке (если он в какой-то обертке), а строку к указателю на char (к string_view в современном c++). Тут могут быть небольшие проблемы с широкими кодировками, но их тоже можно привести к массиву байт. Если не понимаете связанных с этим проблем - приводите к utf8.

Далее, для распределения этих массивов между потоками есть разные механизмы, это может быть прямая отправка конкретному потоку (Point-to-Point communication), или можно запихать все строки в один буфер, и указать, каким потокам какие части этого буфера нужны. Тут я подробностей не помню, но обратите внимание, что некоторые функции MPI копируют весь буфер, даже если потоку нужна только его часть, нужно читать документацию.

Я бы рекомендовал обратить внимание на [Boost.MPI](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/mpi.html), но если вы не знакомы с boost или хотя бы со стандартной библиотекой C++, непосредственный вызов функций на C  может быть проще.

Comment: Спасибо вам за пояснения. В итоге передачу осуществила с помощью Boost.MPI, он поддерживает передачу string, что оказалось очень удобным. Плюс информации чего как делать много)